# Zabbix - Is it possible to invoke an external api based on the http responsecode received

Tags: zabbix

We have a Zabbix web scenario in which the status of an API is monitored.
If the API call returns certain http status code (500 for example) then another API (no control on the functionality of this API, 3rd party maintained) needs to be invoked.

Please advise if a Zabbix trigger can invoke another webscenario? or is there any alternative approach to this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A Trigger cannot invoke a scenario, but can invoke a script through an Action. The script can contain `curl`, allowing you to invoke an API.

See: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/notifications/action/operation/remote_command